# Create view from table in external database with other usercredentials

Tags: mysql, view

Is it possibly to create a view of a table from another database on the same server, but with other usercredentials?

Any ideas how this could be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using FEDERATED engine - your problem should be "easily" solved. A great article can be found at [MySQL website](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-federated-storage.html).